# change NSTextField background while mouse over

Tags: cocoa, macos

in iPhoto when editing an event's property, if you move your mouse over a text field(like event name), the background will change, and become editable, when mouse move out, the background change back, so I'm wondering how to implement that kind of text field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Subclass `NSTextField`, add a tracking rect (some steps are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MouseTrackingEvents/MouseTrackingEvents.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstrackingarea)) and modify the field properties in your `mouseEntered:`/`mouseExited:` methods.